# Loop / indexing query in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, syntax, for-loop

I have a matlab code that I eventually want to use to find the output from 50 sources randomly placed inside a grid and summed; at the moment I can get it to work for one source; the code is something like this;

```
%required constants
ro = 5*10^-6;
po = 40;
a = 5.9336*10^-6;
D = 2*10^-9;
f = 2.6835*10^-7;
mult = a/(4*f*D);
rc = 6.0260e-05
pop = 5:1:495;


%initialise 500 x 500 array to zero
pp = zeros(500,500);



i = 1;


while i < 2

    x(i) = randsample(pop,1);
    y(i) = randsample(pop,1);

%randomly selections an x,y point on grid - the below if loop sets a boundary of %+/70     %microns from the point to examine. The min lower point in x and y is 1, max 500;    

    if x(i) - 70 > 0 && x(i) + 70 <= 500 && y(i) - 70 > 0 && y(i) + 70 <= 500

        xb(i) = x(i) - 70;
        xu(i) = x(i) + 70;

        yb(i) = y(i) - 70;
        yu(i) = y(i) + 70;

    elseif x(i) - 70 < 0 && x(i) + 70 <= 500 && y(i) - 70 > 0 && y(i) + 70 <= 500

        xb(i) = 1;
        xu(i) = x(i) + 70;

        yb(i) = y(i) - 70;
        yu(i) = y(i) + 70;

    elseif x(i) - 70 > 0 && x(i) + 70 > 500 && y(i) - 70 > 0 && y(i) + 70 <= 500

        xb(i) = x(i) - 70;
        xu(i) = 500;

        yb(i) = y(i) - 70;
        yu(i) = y(i) + 70;

    elseif x(i) - 70 > 0 && x(i) + 70 <= 500 && y(i) - 70 < 0 && y(i) + 70 <= 500

        xb(i) = x(i) - 70;
        xu(i) = x(i) + 70;

        yb(i) = 1;
        yu(i) = y(i) + 70;

    elseif x(i) - 70 > 0 && x(i) + 70 <= 500 && y(i) - 70 > 0 && y(i) + 70 > 500

        xb(i) = x(i) - 70;
        xu(i) = x(i) + 70;

        yb(i) = 1;
        yu(i) = 500

    end


    %now test boundaries established, we use our equation for the source....   

    for xm = xb:xu
        for ym = yb:yu
            H(xm,ym) = (sqrt((xm - x).^2 + (ym - y).^2))*10^-6;
            %H is a distance; if beyond rc, source is zero
            if  H(xm,ym) > rc 
                pp(xm,ym) = 0;
            elseif  H(xm,ym) < ro
                pp(xm,ym) = po;
            else
                pp(xm,ym) = po + mult.*(H(xm,ym).^2 - ro^2 - 2.*rc^2.*log(H(xm,ym)./ro));
            end
        end
    end
    i = i + 1
end
```

This works very well for just one source; the code as it is produces a single source perfectly. But I'm running into trouble trying to generalise upwards to while i < 51 ; basically, I want to modify the code so that a 500 x 500 matrix pp is created each run of the while loop, and instead of over-writing the previous ones, these pps are summed together so get all sources.

I tried modifying H and pp etc to be functions of i,xm,ym etc but this didn't seem to work for me - any suggestions / examples of how I might do this? Thanks!

Comment: apologies, it's MATLAB...one moment and I'll try to add that!

Comment: Do you actually want the 500x500 pp matrix to be saved for each iteration, or it a single 500x500 pp matrix that is the sum of teh entire loop what you're after? Or both?

Comment: Both ideally - so I can understand better how to code this! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have matlab in front of me, ATM, but I think this should work. I didn't bother checking if `xm` or `ym` could be negative or zero or greater than 500.

For creating an 500 x 500 X 51 pp, simply do...

This will maintain a running sum.

```
pp = zeros([500 500 51]);
% removed for brevity

for i=1:51 %instead of while, which is less efficient
    % removed for brevity
    for xm = xb:xu
        for ym = yb:yu
            H(xm,ym) = (sqrt((xm - x).^2 + (ym - y).^2))*10^-6;
            %H is a distance; if beyond rc, source is zero
            if  H(xm,ym) > rc 
                pp(xm,ym,i) =  0;
            elseif  H(xm,ym) < ro
                pp(xm,ym,i) = po;
            else
                pp(xm,ym,i) =mult.*(H(xm,ym).^2 - ro^2 - 2.*rc^2.*log(H(xm,ym)./ro));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This gives you a 500 x 500 x 51 matrix pp. Any given 500x500 can be extracted using `pp(:,:,index)`. The sum can be obtained with `sum(pp,3)`

Comment: Thank you! This works great; the only change one has to make is to ALSO define H as a function of i so that H(xm,ym,i). Thanks again - sorry for delay in reply!